# facebook page tab app name in url

Tags: facebook

Can I set application name in url? like I can set it for the page e.g. facebook.com/mypagename/myapp instead of facebook.com/mypagename/app_123123123 ? I know that I can use apps.facebook.com/myapp but I want to use it on the page, not there.

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately you can not.