# Facebook: Change the URL to an app inside a page

Tags: facebook, settings, facebook-apps, facebook-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [facebook page tab app name in url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172661/facebook-page-tab-app-name-in-url)

Just a quick question to figure out if its even possible or not.

We have an app inside a page, so we can direct-link to the app inside the page with:
http://www.facebook.com/page/app_1234567989874

My question is;
Is it possible to change the "app_1234567989874" part to something more readable or memorable like "appname"? Maybe after a certain amount of likes or visits?

It noted that this question is about the same as http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/12172661/facebook-page-tab-app-name-in-url but that one has no answers so I thought I'd try again.

Cheers in advance!

Comment: Completely overlooked, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Facebook doesn't have the option to change your app link the way you can change your profile, or page name.  You can use a free link shortening service like http://www.tinyurl.com or http://www.yak.me for something shorter and easier to remember.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Too bad it isn't possible but hey, management will have to live with it :)